# Can i Backup Magento Log file every day and delete it after 15 day?

Tags: magento, batch-file

I try to Backup Magento log file (system.log) everyday but i found

I try to make code batch with easy way but if  system.log is working same time with my batch file my batch is error because system.log will can't move

I try yo copy and delete system.log after copy my batch is continue working but system.log will not delete because system.log still working

this is my example code pls help me for this problem

**example code 1**

```
@echo off
echo ### Backing up directory...
delete C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\backup\backup3.log
move C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\backup\backup2.log C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\backup\backup3.log
move C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\backup\backup1.log C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\backup\backup2.log

move C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\system.log C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\backup\backup1.log
echo Backup Complete!

@echo off
```

**example code 2**

```
copy C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\system.log C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\backup\backup1.log
delete C:\xamp\www\magento\var\log\system.log
```

**PS Can i save Backup.log with date and delete after 15 day?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change system.log file name in app/Mage.php line 808
$file = empty($file) ? 'system.log' : $file;

you can change above code with following

```
 $filename_custom = 'system_'.date('Y-m-d').'.log';
 $file = empty($file) ? $filename_custom : $file;
```

then you will get log file with date. now you will have all log file date wise just need to delete files which are older then 15 days.